# What is the naming convention for the Factory Method?

Tags: design-patterns, naming-conventions, factory-method

**Introduction**

> The MacApp Macintosh application framework [App89] always declares the
>   abstract operation that defines the factory method as Class*
>   DoMakeClass(), where Class is the Product class.

This quote has leaded me to the question about naming conventions for the Factory Method design pattern.

**Expectations**

I expect to see best practices or helpful examples, which provide clear factory methods naming.

Since it could depend on a language, let's consider a set of the most popular languages: C#, Java, C++ and JavaScript.

**Context**

For a context I propose to consider the following class structure. We have two abstract classes: Document and Application. The Application contains a list of documents and it should be possible to create a new document. The Application has a factory method `CreateDocument()`.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The convention, if any, is probably language dependent...

Comment: I'm interested in C#, C++ and JavaScript. I tried to find anything about naming conventions, but have only one (about the MacApp) putted in my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO, the method name is dependent on context and the nature of the object being created. Maybe this is why you've not found any clear conventions. For example, a `Create()` method might be right in one context while `Open()` or `Build()` might be more appropriate in others.

Comment: I agree and +1 for context. Context is King *quoted from Applying Domain Driven Design*.

Comment: The naming convention is a thing that exists or not. It should not depend on a context or a programming language.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need a naming convention? `CreateDocument()` appears to be a well-named, self-documenting factory method.

Comment: Actually I don't need this convention, because I successfully live without it :) I just wanted to know is a naming convention exist or not. But in response I see only questions about context, language and so on... I expected to see best practices or helpful examples. Now I believe, there is no strong conventions related to this design pattern. The best practice would be using of "Do" or "Make" prefixes to mark a factory method in some languages, which have not embedded virtual or abstract methods (for example, javascript). I think, that my question should be reformulated to become more clear:)

Answer (score 1):

There are no strong conventions related to this design pattern. The best practice would be using of "`Do`" or "`Make`" prefixes to mark a factory method in some languages, which have not embedded virtual or abstract methods (for example, javascript).